# Setting the Page.Theme in code makes the css files get linked to twice

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

In ASP.NET we have until now only had one theme, which was specified in the web.config.  I recently started switching the Theme in the base page `PreInit` based on the `Request.Url.Host` value, say *domain1.com* was the original & we are now adding *domain2.com* with its own style. Since doing this all the `<link rel="stylesheet...>` tags are injected twice into the page. The *domain1* ones which were always injected at the very start of the `<head>` section, then the `<title>` tag, followed by all the stylesheet link tags again for which ever theme is explicitly set in the page PreInit.

As I understand it ASP.NET will include every css file in the themes folder automatically, at which event in the page lifecycle does it do this?

Comment: do you want to include css at runtime or you want know the last event when these css files included before rendering to page?

Comment: The later, I'm really just trying to debug why the css is loading twice

Comment: What if you want to exclude the css which you don't want at PreRender Event ?

Comment: I could do that, but it's really hacky & I'm concerned that we've borked the page life-cycle somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the issue, we were attaching to the PreInit event handler rather than overriding the `OnPreInit` method on the page, which resulted in this weird side effect.  Seems that .NET does some funky magic in the preinit to setup the theme default from the web.config which doesn't get fully overridden if you set the `Theme` property in the event handler rather than in the method. Most likely this is due to the fact that events don't have a guaranteed order of execution so it's happening either too early or too late.